# Isekai manga or manhua about a villainess who was a daughter of the duke and got her engagement with the prince annulled

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I'm not sure if I remember correctly but she was a daughter of the duke and got her engagement with the prince annulled.

She then went to marry an emperor or king from another land, the emperor had long black hair and dark skin, exotic looking.  Then her ex-fiancé regretted the annulment.

I'm not sure if it's isekai or rebirth. But it is fantasy.

Comment: What was science-fiction or fantasy about it?

Comment: @Jenayah Isekai = reborn in another world.

Comment: @jo1storm right, missed that in the title. I'll retract my close vote. Unrelated, but I thought isekai was simply being transported into another world? Not necessarily rebirth?

Comment: @Jenayah yeah, pretty much. In any case, it is sci fi or fantasy :)

Comment: Thank you for you comments. Ummm... Im not sure if its Isekai or Rebirth. But it is fantasy.

Comment: You appear to have lost your original login; please see [this page](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts so you can edit your question.

Comment: do you remember anything else about the story? When in the story did the annulment and marriage to the emperor/king happen? How certain are you about the dark skin/exotic look? As is, I have found 4-5 manga that roughly fit this description. Though most of them have the emperor/king/prince have short black hair and/or light skin. They fit all the other points though.